# First and second moments of a piecewise time series

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, time-series

Let $x=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ be a first-order autoregressive process, $AR(1)$. Since $x$ is an $AR(1)$ process, it is defined as follows:

$x_t=\mu+\phi x_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$

where $\mu$ and $\phi$ are constants, and $\epsilon_t$ is a $IID$ random variable distributed Normally with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Now consider another process, $y=\{y_1,y_2,...\}$ defined as follows:

$y_t = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x_t+y_{t-1} & : mod(t,a)\neq 1\\
       x_t  & : mod(t,a)= 1\\
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$

where $a$ is a constant.  How to calculate the mean and variance of process $y$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Dasherman I was able to determine the mean of process _y_. Process _y_ essentially is the combination of an AR(1) process, _x_, and a new process that is a cumsum of elements of process _x_. The mean of _AR(1)_ process is pretty straightforward. The mean of the cumsum process is _(a+2)/2_ times the mean of _AR(1)_ process. The overall mean of _y_ is the weighted average of _AR(1)_ and the cumsum processes. The weight of _AR(1)_ process is _1/a_ and that of the cumsum process is _(a-1)/a_. I still do not know how to determine the variance of _y_.